# Error while updating samba4

Tags: samba4

I'm trying to update my RHEL6.9 by running **yum update --security**

But I keep getting this error saying that samba4-common requires a certain version of samba4-libs which has already been installed on that machine.

If I remove samba4-libs first and then install the new version it works, but for some reason it just can't update it.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: error message]

Thanks!

Comment: Your private repos are out of sync. Contact whoever maintains them.

Comment: what does it mean they are out of sync? You can see in the screenshot that it is trying to update to a newer version of samba.

Comment: That means the versions of the packages in that repo do not match with each other. Again, you need to contact whoever maintains that repo in your company. We cannot help you with this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't understand this - I had installed that package from repo X, and then created another repository named Y (which only contains security updates), in order to update my RHEL6.9 machine. All the other packages were updated perfectly fine except that one. The whole point is to update that package so I'm confused why you say the versions should match. I'd be really grateful if you could elaborate your resolution as my team maintains that repository. Thank you!